# Adding oembed plugin to ckeditor

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I used [ckBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder) to create my own custom editor with certain plugins.I chose the oembed plugin, followed the installation procedures but I kept getting a weird error.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of undefined
```

Are there other configurations that need to be adjusted before using it?!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out if you modify the ckeditor multiple times, you need to clear your cache in order to reflect any new plugins.